# Assembly ID is getting appended when zip file is created by maven

Tags: maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

xml and pom.xml which creates jar file and then zip file with some artifacts including jar file. But when i run maven install zip file is getting created as GenerateMissingUsersReport-bin.zip instead I want it to create as GenerateMissingUsersReport.zip. I have set as false. But no difference.

Any pointers?

Here is dep.xml

```
<id>bin</id>  
<baseDirectory>../</baseDirectory>  
<formats>  
<format>zip</format>  
</formats>  
<fileSets>  
<fileSet>  
<directory>${project.basedir}</directory>  
<outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>  
<includes>  
<include>README*</include>  
<include>LICENSE*</include>  
<include>NOTICE*</include>  
</includes>  
</fileSet>  
<fileSet>  
<directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>  
<outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>  
<includes>  
<include>*.jar</include>  
</includes>  
</fileSet>  
<fileSet>  
<directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>  
<includes>  
<include>plugin.xml</include>  
</includes>   
<outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>  
</fileSet>  
</fileSets>
```

Here is pom.xml

```
<finalName>GenerateMissingUsersReport</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                        <finalName>GenerateMissingUsersReport</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyID>false</appendAssemblyID>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-zip</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    <excludes>
    <exclude>plugin.xml</exclude>
    </excludes></configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 24):

Add the following line under configurations element of the pom

```
<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
```

Also make sure you use the latest version of the assembly plugin

```
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5.5</version>
```